# Class 'SoapClient' not found while runnig laradock containers

Tags: php, docker, soap, docker-compose, laradock

I'm using [laradock](https://laradock.io/) as my local environment and I'm getting **Class 'SoapClient' not found** while using an online gateway that utilizes soap. I tried modifying configuration files as below:

In all *php-fpm/phpX.ini* files I uncommented this line:

```
extension=php_soap.dll // uncommented
```

In *php-fpm/Dokcerfile* and *workspace/Dockerfile* I set this line to true:

```
ARG INSTALL_SOAP=true
```

And in *.env* file I got these lines:

```
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SOAP=true
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SOAP=true
```

I build with command:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

But the error still exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange. But All I had to do was to change **INSTALL_SOAP** to false in *php-fpm/Dokcerfile*

```
ARG INSTALL_SOAP = false
```

And just make that true in *workspace/Dockerfile*. Having them both **true** was causing this error!